# How can I access an attribute of a model which is a foreignkey to another model in the views.py file

Tags: django

For example I have two models .Brand model which is a foreign key to another model Item. The Brand  model has an attribute best_seller which is a boolean field recording whether a certain brand of items is a best seller. In my views I want to filter only the items whose brand is a best seller.How can I do this

This is how my models.py looks like

```
class Brand(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
best_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.title


class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
new_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images')
old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
slug = models.SlugField()
description = models.TextField()
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__ (self):
    return self.title
```

Then this the views.py file

```
def home(request):
brand = Brand.objects.filter(best_seller=True)
bests = Item.objects.filter(brand=True).order_by('-id')[:12]
context = {
    'items': items,
    'bests': bests
}
return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

After doing this there's nothing being rendered on the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not filtering the bests with the brands:

```
brand = Brand.objects.filter(best_seller=True)
bests = Item.objects.filter(brand__in=brand).order_by('-id')[:12]
```

notice I added the __in to the brand filter, since the 'brand' queryset returns a queryset and not one object.

Comment: I have tried that  and I got the following errorValueError at /
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.